# How to re-assign two variables in a conditional UPDATE

Tags: mysql, update

Consider a simple update as

```
SET @var1 = 20;
SET @var2 = 26;
UPDATE table1 SET
    col1=IF(@var1>50, @var1 := @var1-col4, @var1 := @var1+col5),
    col2=IF(@var2>50, @var2 := @var2-col6, @var2);
```

How we can change two variables in one condition. For example, consider that when `@var1<50`, we want to change not only `@var1 := @var1+col5`, but also re-assign `@var2 := @var2 + 100`. In fact, regardless of the condition 2, we want to increase `@var2`, if the first condition fails (the second part).

Is it possible to re-assign two user-variable in a `IF STATEMENT` or we need to add another `IF STATEMENT`?

This will be equivalent to

```
SET @var1 = 20;
SET @var2 = 26;
UPDATE table1 SET
    col1=IF(@var1>50, @var1 := @var1-col4, @var1 := @var1+col5),
    virtual_col=IF(@var1>50, NULL, @var2 := @var2+100),
    col2=IF(@var2>50, @var2 := @var2-col6, @var2);
```

Here we have created a useless column, not to collect the data, but to repeat the `IF STATEMENT` for the `@var2`. Obviously, it is not good from performance point of view, as we are running a useless `UPDATE` action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to do two assignments in one `IF` statement.

There are several ways; I present one, using `CASE` statement:

```
SET @var1 = 20;
SET @var2 = 26;
UPDATE table1 SET
    col1=IF(
      @var1>50, 
      @var1 := @var1-col4, 
      CASE
        WHEN @var1 := @var1+col5 IS NULL THEN NULL
        WHEN @var2 := @var2 + 100 IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE @var1
      END
    ),
col2=IF(@var2>50, @var2 := @var2-col6, @var2);
```

The idea is to create a `CASE` statement where first `WHEN` clauses fail. They fail because we want them to, but along they way they get evaluated.

But in order for them to get evaluated, they must first computer the assignment expression, such as `@var1 := @var1+col5` and `@var2 := @var2 + 100`.

`CASE` expressions work from first `WHEN` clause to the next one, and must work in this order.

Please consider reading more about it in my presentation of last year's Percona Live London (2011) conference. For referece, relevant slides are **13** - **15**: [Programmatic queries: things you can code with sql](http://www.slideshare.net/shlominoach/programmatic-queries-thingsyoucancodewithsql)

Comment: Strangely, this didn't work for me. I went with [using a subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9385626/526741) where the ignore columns in the subquery were variable assignments.